# lambda.invoke call through Node AWS SDK is timing out at 5 minutes while Lambda is completing under 4 minutes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a Lambda function that is set to timeout at 5 minutes, and occasionally when I invoke the function using the `node` SDK, I am getting a timeout error after 5 minutes.

However, when I have checked the CloudWatch logs after getting the client-side error, and am seeing the function successfully complete after ~3:30 minutes of execution time.

I have also noticed that the client side will log the timeout 2 minutes before the CloudWatch logs read that the function completed (ie, client side error timestamps at 4:08 and the CloudWatch successful end timestamps at 4:10), but I am assuming that is a lag between log writes, not run time. Thought I would mention it just in case that is something worth thinking more about.

From what I can tell, when the function runs under two minutes, it is consistently getting a positive response.

Code looks like this:

```
let aws_config = new AWS.Config({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: credentials,
    httpOptions: { 
        proxy: process.env.HTTP_PROXY,
        timeout: 300000
    }
})

var lambda = new AWS.Lambda(aws_config);

lambda.invoke(params, (err, data: Result) => {
  ...
}
```

Error looks like this:

```
{ TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 300000ms
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at Socket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:661:40)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:449:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:425:11)
message: 'Connection timed out after 300000ms',
  code: 'TimeoutError',
  time: 2018-10-05T20:08:35.719Z,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true } 'TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 300000ms\n    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)\n    at Socket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:661:40)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)\n    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:449:8)\n    at ontimeout (timers.js:425:11)'
```

Comment: Did you try to increase Memory limit for your lambda function?

Comment: I can try, but I am really thinking there is a SDK/client side problem, as I'm not seeing errors in the console. Also, max memory usage is under 100MB.

Comment: What's missing here is the Lambda function's code, and the function execution log. Most of the times I've seen this kind of behaviour was when the function did not terminate *correctly*, i.e., did not call the callback function but simply finished the run.

Comment: @Kalev - function code is large. It returns most of the time and logs are showing successful return, not just successful run of the code. So I do think this is client side.

Comment: @getglad - when you run the function with the same parameters from the AWS web console what behaviour do you witness?
Also, creating a minimal example that reproduces the behaviour would go a long way towards isolating the issue.

Comment: @Kalev - it runs successful. Also do not have this problem using python SDK. Will work on getting your minimal example up.

Comment: @getglad As I am also have faced this issue in lambda. when I am using third party call and its connection still open so, lambda is waiting for terminating that event. So its good to you provide your code what exactly you use

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

Here'e a related SO posting:
[Why does AWS Lambda function always time out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621776/why-does-aws-lambda-function-always-time-out)

Comment: `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` this solve problem but its not good practice because when you `false` the `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop ` than `AWS Lambda to freeze the process soon after the callback is called`

Comment: callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop isn't bad practice and in fact in almost every production setting you'll have to use it for when you have open (My)SQL connection pools etc, it's just a fact of life on Lamdba unfortunately. That being said if the function has something you CAN close then do it rather than using the solution above.